# Cluster shared disk available checked failed

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm doing sql cluster and I'm getting the following error:-

> cluster shared disk available checked failed error

And with the following warnings below thereby preventing me from continuing the installation

1. Microsoft cluster service(MSCS)
2. Cluster verification error
3. Window firewal.

Comment: The installer won't go anywhere if the Windows cluster has failed verification, you need to fix this and ensure all your shared storage is set up correctly before you can even think about installing SQL Server.

Comment: steoleary, thank you for your reply but i have check my shared storage and to me it seams right. please can you help me with any article or screen shot that clearly explain how to set up the share storage so that i can compare and make correction perhaps i'm not doing things right?Thank you in advance.I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite an old question, but I stumbled on this while doing cluster configuration myself. Now when I found the reason for such issue I thought I should post it here so that people like me could find the solution. 
So the reason this validation fails at the time of SQL server cluster Installation that the only shared disk drive configured in windows cluster gets added by default in quorum, due to which the disk can not be shared (that's what SQL server thinks, also try running windows server cluster validation that will also fail).

So to overcome this problem make sure that shared drive is not added before configuring the windows cluster.
the order of installation should be

1. Install Windows Cluster on all the nodes (Ignore storage validation)
2. Configure iSCSI drive on all nodes
3. Add iSCCI drive in Windows cluster
4. Install SQL server cluster (by this time the SQL validation failure should not appear)

I followed the following post which has all steps individually documented

https://sqlserverscribbles.com/2013/06/17/how-to-install-cluster-in-windows-2008-and-windows-2012/